# Como colocar uma borda em um <tr> que apareça por cima da borda do <td>?

Tags: html, css, css-border

Estava desenvolvendo uma tela, que continha uma tabela com um estilo no `tr:hover` para quando o usuário passasse o mouse sobre as linhas da mesma, elas ficassem com um aspecto diferente. Tudo estava indo bem até o momento em que eu resolvi que queria colocar uma *"bendita borda"* em volta da linha no `:hover`, sendo que os `<td>`'s já possuem borda.

## [Demo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4V6t/)

Acontece que a borda do `<tr>` não aparece na frente. E então o que fazer?

Comment: @PauloRoberto: cara, a gramática de sua edição não está melhor não... "da qual possui", "do qual o usuário passa o mouse"...

Answer (score 3):

### Explicação baseada em experimentos:

Acontece que quando as bordas da tabela estão com o atributo *collapsed*, os `<tr>`'s e `<td>`'s compartilham das mesmas bordas. Sendo assim, não há como exibir a borda do `<tr>` ao mesmo tempo que a do `<td>`... mas isso não é toda a história.

Existe uma regra para que a borda definida no estilo do `<tr>` seja usada, ao invés daquela definida no estilo do `<td>`.

Experimentalmente, notei que bordas mais espessas, possuem prioridade. Portanto se a borda mais espessa estiver no `<tr>`, esta é a que será usada. Se ambas tiverem a mesma espessura, a borda definida para o `<td>` será usada.

- 3 pixels (maior prioridade)
- 2 pixels
- 1 pixel (menor prioridade)

Usar unidades distintas também não parece afetar... o que importa é a medida real calculada. Se *0.1em* resultar em 2 pixels, então terá mais prioridade que a borda de *1px*.

Estilos diferentes, também possuem prioridades diferentes. No Chrome e no Firefox vale a seguinte fila de prioridade:

- hidden (maior prioridade)
- double
- solid
- dashed
- dotted (menor prioridade)

<sub>P.S.: Estou ignorando todos os estilos de bordas 3D</sub>

A ordem dos estilos, ou colocar `!important` no estilo não tem efeito.

### Como solucionar o problema?

Para resolver o problema original, com uma borda de 1 pixel, podemos usar um **hack**:
usar o estilo double com 1px na `<tr>`, e um estilo *solid* com *1px* na `<td>`, fazendo com que o estilo definido para a `<td>` apareça finalmente.

```css
tr:hover {
    border: 1px double red;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

## [Demo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4V6t/1/)

---

Comment: @PauloRoberto: Já aqui, sua edição ajudou... realmente *"estória"*, é só para contos. Como tudo aqui são fatos, então *"história"* cai bem melhor.

Comment: @PauloRoberto: Além de ter ajudado com os TD's e TR's... valeu cara!

Comment: de nada, disponha :}